# add mysql query values to an php array

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to add all the query values to an array.

here is my code:

```
$value = $_POST['hospitalname'];
$from = $_POST['from'];
$to = $_POST['to'];
if($_POST["Submit"]=="Submit") {
    for ($i=0; $i<sizeof($value); $i++) {
        $sql = "SELECT sl_id from mfb_servicelog where h_id LIKE ('".$value[$i]."')";
        $result = mysql_query($sql);
        while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
            $slid = $row["sl_id"];
            for ($x=0; $x<sizeof($slid);$x++) {
                echo $slid[$x];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If I print the result of $slid, it gives me this

```
1333853863873885215251126112711281129113023392488248924902491249224932494249524962497
```

These all are `sl_id`, and result of the query `$sql`. This is fine.

Now I want to put all these value into an array so that I can call this from a query like I am calling the $value in the above $sql query.

But my `echo $slid($x)` gives me this output, whic is the first digit of each value.

```
13333551111122222222222
```

Please suggest me the right way to do this.

Comment: Please note that `mysql_` functions are deprecated! Use PDO or `mysqli_` instead

Comment: `$slid` is a string, not an array. So `$slid[$x]` is the x'th character of `$slid`. You only get the first character because `sizeof($slid)` is 1.

Comment: what will be the right way to do this then... @Barmar

Comment: Like in the answer that sgt Bose posted.

Comment: @Barmar...I am able to get all the values in the slid... but I am unable to understand how can I separate each values... Like if I run a query using WHERE sl_id LIKE ('".$slid[$i]."').... it should run that query for each values in the $slid.

Answer (score 0):

Just store them in an array instead of a normal variable. Try with -

```
$slid[] = $row["sl_id"];
```

**Update**

```
if (!in_array($row["sl_id"], $slid)) {
    $slid[] = $row["sl_id"];
}
```

And define `$slid` before the loop starts - `$slid = array();`

Or you can use `array_unique()`

For your code it should be -

```
   $slid = array();
   while ($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        if (!in_array($row["sl_id"], $slid)) {
             $slid[] = $row["sl_id"];
        }
   }

   foreach($slid as $id) {
      echo $id."<br>";
   }
```

Comment: Its repeating all the values.

13313338513338538613338538638713338538638738813338538638738852113338538638738852152513338538638738852152511261333853863873885215251126112713338538638738852152511261127

Comment: Yes, because you output the values of slid for every while loop ;) Place the for loop after the while :) Hint: You can use foreach, which is easier :P

Comment: Well after so many edits...I am really confused... let me verify my code with with you.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Now the echo returns all the values in a line. But how can I get a single value from it....like I am getting by ($value[i])

Comment: I actually need to add this to another query which will run for each and every values of sl_id

Comment: They all are inside of the foreach. Just store it when needed.

Comment: well it returns 133133133133133133133133133133133133133133133133133133133133133133133

Comment: the query will be like select count(info_type) from mfb_agent_status_details where info_type='M' and sl_id=$sl_id;

Comment: So put the query inside the loop. you will get the id in `$id`